# How to get latest records based on two foreign id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `CenterService` entity (table `center_services`) and there is two columns `center_id` and `service_id`.

I have an array of services ids and I need collection in return but without of duplication `center_id` and `service_id`. I only need last record of that combination.

This is how I try:

```
$requiredServices = Service::whereRequiredService(true)->pluck('id');

return CenterService::whereIn('service_id', $requiredServices)->latest()->get();
```

but it's just order that collection with all duplicate data.

Comment: Hello Knubbe! Maybe using unique can help you. Something like $requiredServices = $requiredServices>unique('service_id');